# Auto upload files ftp

Tags: ftp

I have been looking all over on the web for a script to take files on my computer and ftp to a folder on my server. I would like for the script to check the folder periodically threw the day for new files to upload. Could someone please let me know if this possible and if so point me in the right direction. I really do not have any programming experience other than minimal java script. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I presume you're running Windows?

If you are, I would use Excel and VBA to drive winscp - http://winscp.net

A simple VBA script using the DIR command in Excel and keeping a time in a cell in a spreadsheet should do the trick. Write your script to check for files newer than the time in the cell, and add any which it finds to a winscp script.

Alternatively you could use something like Dropbox to sync files, which is much easier but slightly less flexible.